# How to list the machine name along with running programs list in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script to check if Firefox is running in my Linux machine like;

```
ps -ef|grep firefox
```

this will list all the instances of firefox running in my machine, showing their PIDs, so that I can manually kill them. My question is, is it possible to display the machine name also in this list? If there are multiple instances, each line should contain the machine name (or IP) also. In my shellscript, i did something like;

```
hostname
ps -ef|grep firefox
```

which returns the hostname once, and multiple instances are listed below that one by one. How can I print machine name (or IP) also along with each line?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
ps -ef | grep [f]irefox | xargs -I{} echo "$(hostname) {}"
```

Notice the brackets around 'f' in firefox. This prevents your `grep` command from showing up in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
ps -ef | egrep '[/ ]firefox' | sed "s/^/$(hostname -s) : /"
```